# Android - strings.xml cannot escape single quote

Tags: android, android-xml

This is the error i got:

```
Execution failed for task ':MyPackage:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/abc/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/secondary_text').
```

My `@string/secondary_text` is like this:

```
<string name="secondary_text">They&#39;re all free to download.</string>
```

I'm escaping the single quote here, I tried `&apos;` too, still didn't work. The only thing worked is I changed `They're` to `They are`.

Does anyone know how to escape single quote on Android?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: @MC Emperor that's true. Flagged as Duplicate.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `\'` for your single quote.